# Root directory with PHP on Apache and IIS

Tags: php, apache, iis, directory, root

Is there a `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` equivalent which would work on both Apache and IIS without having to change configuration files? Or maybe some workarounds?

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing, can you clarify?

Comment: The problem is that $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] does not work on IIS as I know and it's not a good idea to use it. Also I am searching for a solution which would work on lower versions of PHP as well (lower than PHP 5).

Comment: Maybe you could use the PHP function `getcwd();` (PHP4/PHP5) and some logic to get what you need?

Comment: On some Unix variants, getcwd() will return FALSE if any one of the parent directories does not have the readable or search mode set, even if the current directory does.

Comment: I've worked with dozens of UNIX servers, some shared some independent, never has `getcwd` failed. You should be more focused on creating a viable solution instead of catering to exceptions that you'll likely never encounter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IIS

```
if(empty($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) && !empty($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])) { 
  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = str_replace( '\\', '/', substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], 0, 0 - strlen($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])));
} 
if(empty($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) && !empty($_SERVER['PATH_TRANSLATED'])) { 
  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = str_replace( '\\', '/', substr(str_replace('\\\\', '\\', $_SERVER['PATH_TRANSLATED']), 0, 0 - strlen($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])));
}
```